# Download tensorflow 1.12 distribution along with all compatible libraries

Tags: tensorflow

I am having problem having tensorflow 1.12 distribution along with all compatible libraries in one conda environment.

I tried:

```
conda create -n env_name tf12
conda activate tf12
conda install pandas scikit-learn matplotlib notebook ##installing usual Data Science packages that does include numpy and scipy 
pip install tensorflow==1.12
```

But I got that tensorflow is not available (version > 2 are there though). Can you please help me how to get all cunda, tensoflow packages and all other necessary libraries to run tensorflow 12 version successfully?

Comment: Installing it at the same time with `conda install tensorflow==1.12 pandas scikit-learn matplotlib notebook` should work.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson. tensorflow addson wheel 0.4.0 is not avilable for Windows.

Comment: I just did the line in my first comment followed `pip install tensorflow-addons` on linux and ended up with tensorflow-addons 0.14.0 which worked well without conflicts. Don't have a Windows machine to test on, sorry.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson. Thanks. But I am looking for addson 0.4.0 that is compatible with tf 1.12

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson. I found that the lowest even in UNIX machine is 0.5.0, so I just used that with TF 1.12. Thank you.